# Handling Multiple Determinate Progress Bars

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

First of all I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/613ca9995c29ac6be655) of the complete file for reference.

What I wanted was to upload multiple files with exclusive determinate progress bar (separate progress bar for each file)

I have successfully achieved the upload progress and am able to get seperate progress percentage for each file as seen on line 164

```
 Debug.WriteLine(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Progress: {0}, Status: {1}", upload.Guid, currentProgress.Status));
```

I am currently listing the files via Grid Binding as seen on line 117

```
 FA.Add(new FilesAttached
 {
     Filename = fname,
     FileSize = fsize,
     Percent = upload.Progress.BytesSent.ToString()
 });
 await coreDispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
      () =>
           {
              attachments_all.ItemsSource = FA;
           });
```

The problem I have is that the progress does not change at all and I believe the exact excerpt where something is amiss is this

```
private async Task HandleUploadAsync(UploadOperation upload, bool start, string fname, string fsize)
        {
            CoreDispatcher coreDispatcher = Window.Current.Dispatcher;
            try
            {

                percent.Add("0");
                Debug.WriteLine("Running: " + upload.Guid, "");
                FA.Add(new FilesAttached
                {
                    Filename = fname,
                    FileSize = fsize,
                    Percent = upload.Progress.BytesSent.ToString()
                });
                await coreDispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                            () =>
                            {
                                attachments_all.ItemsSource = FA;
                            });
                Progress<UploadOperation> progressCallback = new Progress<UploadOperation>(UploadProgress);
                if (start)
                {
                    // Start the upload and attach a progress handler.
                    await upload.StartAsync().AsTask(cts.Token, progressCallback);
                }
                else
                {
                    // The upload was already running when the application started, re-attach the progress handler.
                    await upload.AttachAsync().AsTask(cts.Token, progressCallback);
                }

                ResponseInformation response = upload.GetResponseInformation();

                Debug.WriteLine(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Completed: {0}, Status Code: {1}", upload.Guid,
                    response.StatusCode), "");
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Canceled: " + upload.Guid, "");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (!IsExceptionHandled("Error", ex, upload))
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        private void UploadProgress(UploadOperation upload)
        {
            // UploadOperation.Progress is updated in real-time while the operation is ongoing. Therefore,
            // we must make a local copy at the beginning of the progress handler, so that we can have a consistent
            // view of that ever-changing state throughout the handler's lifetime.
            BackgroundUploadProgress currentProgress = upload.Progress;

            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Progress: {0}, Status: {1}", upload.Guid,
                currentProgress.Status));
            FilesAttached newFA = new FilesAttached();
            newFA.RaisePropertyChanged("Percent");
            double percentSent = 100;
            if (currentProgress.TotalBytesToSend > 0)
            {
                percentSent = currentProgress.BytesSent * 100 / currentProgress.TotalBytesToSend;

            }

            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                " - Sent bytes: {0} of {1} ({2}%)", currentProgress.BytesSent,
                currentProgress.TotalBytesToSend, percentSent));

            if (currentProgress.HasRestarted)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(" - Upload restarted");
            }

            if (currentProgress.HasResponseChanged)
            {
                // We've received new response headers from the server.
                Debug.WriteLine(" - Response updated; Header count: " + upload.GetResponseInformation().Headers.Count);

                // If you want to stream the response data this is a good time to start.
                // upload.GetResultStreamAt(0);
            }
        }
```

Any help or direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a very similar download manager. You have to change the logic a bit.
I have a class SingleDownload.cs and a DownloadManager.cs.

In the Single Download: 
I have Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and I have Properties like `Title`, `DownloadLink`, `Progress` etc. I manage download in SingleDownload so its easy to change Progress from inside. I have also Methods like `Start()`, `Stop()`, `Dispose()`.

In the DownloadManager.cs(Also a Page) I have an `ObservableList<SingleDownload> downloads` thats is binded to a ListView with progressbar that is binded to Progress. It works like a charm.

So create a class ex. SingleUpload that will manage one upload with its Progress and create a List of uploads and bind it to your `attachments_all`

Comment: I am trying something if that doesnt work ill try your method! Thanks

Comment: Your Suggestion was Correct. Thanks